# Confusing python inheritance

Tags: python, inheritance

---

```
class BaseA(object):
    authors = ['a', 'b']
    author_list = authors

class BaseB(object):
    authors = ['a', 'b']

    def __init__(self, *arg, **kwargs):
        self.author_list = self.authors

class ChildA(BaseA):
    authors = ['c', 'd']

class ChildB(BaseB):
    authors = ['c', 'd']

child_a = ChildA()
child_b = ChildB()
print(child_a.author_list)
print(child_b.author_list)
>>> ['a', 'b']
>>> ['c', 'd']
```

What's the different of the codes? Why do I get different results?

I'm so confusing why parent author_list attributes don't be override.

Can you tell me the principle of python inheritance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Material inside the `class` block is part of the class itself, and is executed *once*, when you define the class.  Material in `__init__` is per-instance, and is executed once *per instance*, every time you instantiate the class.

In your first example (`BaseA`), you create a class attribute `authors`, then create another attribute `author_list` pointing to the same value.  That is it.  Nothing else ever happens.  The fact that `ChildA` inherits from `BaseA` does not cause `author_list = authors` to be re-executed.  `author_list` was over and done with once `BaseA` was defined.

In your second example (`BaseB`), you create a class attribute `authors`.  Then in `__init__` you make a new instance attribute pointing at that same value.  Since you do this in `__init__`, it is re-done for each instance.  So when you instantiate `BaseB`, it gets the new attribute.

Note that you are checking the attributes on the instances `child_a` and `child_b`.  If you check them on the classes (`ChildA.author_list` and `ChildB.author_list`), you will see that both have the same value (`['a', 'b']`).  Because your action in ChildB takes place in `__init__`, it only takes effect when you actually instantiate the class.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that in the second example, `author_list` is set when you create an instance of an object.

When you define class `BaseA` you define the class member `author_list` and that's that, so when you create an instance of `ChildA` nothing is happening to `author_list`. It is just inherited.

When you define `BaseB` there is no member `author_list`. That is created as a instance variable when an instance of `BaseB` is created. So, when you create an instance of `ChildB` the same thing happens, but since `authors` is redefined then it will use the new value of `authors`

Comment: But in the first example, i override authors, and author_list is equal to authors. Before testing, i think author_list will be override and equal to child authors attributes.

Comment: The `author_list = authors ` gets executed only once as I explained in the post.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, it only executed once!

Answer (score 0):

In your BaseB `__init__` function you are calling the Child's authors, not the Parent's authors.
If you wish to call the Parent's authors you would use `BaseB.authors` instead of `self.authors`:

```
class BaseA(object):
    authors = ['a', 'b']
    author_list = authors

class BaseB(object):
    authors = ['a', 'b']

    def __init__(self, *arg, **kwargs):
        self.author_list = BaseB.authors

class ChildA(BaseA):
    authors = ['c', 'd']

class ChildB(BaseB):
    authors = ['c', 'd']

child_a = ChildA()
child_b = ChildB()
print(child_a.author_list)
print(child_b.author_list)
>>> ['a', 'b']
>>> ['a', 'b']
```

In the case where you would be concatenating the authors of the ParentB and the ChildB then you would use both `BaseB.authors` and `self.authors`:

```
class BaseA(object):
    authors = ['a', 'b']
    author_list = authors

class BaseB(object):
    authors = ['a', 'b']

    def __init__(self, *arg, **kwargs):
        self.author_list = BaseB.authors + self.authors

class ChildA(BaseA):
    authors = ['c', 'd']

class ChildB(BaseB):
    authors = ['c', 'd']

child_a = ChildA()
child_b = ChildB()
print(child_a.author_list)
print(child_b.author_list)
>>> ['a', 'b']
>>> ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

## Override

```
class BaseA(object):
    authors = ['a', 'b']
    author_list = authors

class BaseB(object):
    authors = ['a', 'b']

    def __init__(self, *arg, **kwargs):
        self.author_list = self.authors

class ChildA(BaseA):
    authors = ['c', 'd']
    def __init__(self, *arg, **kwargs):
        self.author_list = self.authors

class ChildB(BaseB):
    authors = ['c', 'd']

child_a = ChildA()
child_b = ChildB()
print(child_a.author_list)
print(child_b.author_list)
>>> ['c', 'd']
>>> ['c', 'd']
```

Answer (score 0):

### Recommended way to write your Python code:

```
class BaseA(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.authors = ['a', 'b']

class BaseB(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.authors = ['a', 'b']

class ChildA(BaseA):
    def __init__(self):
        self.authors = ['c', 'd']
    
class ChildB(BaseB):
    def __init__(self):
        self.authors = ['c', 'd']


child_a = ChildA()
child_b = ChildB()
print(child_a.authors)
print(child_b.authors)
>>> ['c', 'd']
>>> ['c', 'd']
```

### Recommended ways to call the Superclass (Base Parent class):

```
class BaseA(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.authors = ['a', 'b']

class BaseB(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.authors = ['a', 'b']

class ChildA(BaseA):
    def __init__(self):
        self.authors = ['c', 'd']
        super().__init__()
    
class ChildB(BaseB):
    def __init__(self):
        self.authors = ['c', 'd']
        BaseB.__init__(self)


child_a = ChildA()
child_b = ChildB()
print(child_a.authors)
print(child_b.authors)
>>> ['a', 'b']
>>> ['a', 'b']
```

#### Esoteric superclass call using one underscore at the end of `__init__ (__init_)`:

```
class BaseA(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.authors = ['a', 'b']

class BaseB(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.authors = ['a', 'b']

class ChildA(BaseA):
    def __init_(self):
        self.authors = ['c', 'd']
    
class ChildB(BaseB):
    def __init_(self):
        self.authors = ['c', 'd']


child_a = ChildA()
child_b = ChildB()
print(child_a.authors)
print(child_b.authors)
>>> ['a', 'b']
>>> ['a', 'b']
```

## CAUTION

#### Using esoteric superclass call results in losing all access to children variables!

Access to methods in the subclass (Child class) will still be accessible, but all access to variables in the subclass (Child class) will be lost completely.